# Vshub constantly logging

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, log-files, visual-studio

I'm managing a small server with Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation from HP on board.
A few months ago, I've installed MSSQL Server 2016 with the latest Management Studio. Since then, there is an app called "vshub" working in background. I've seen people asking how to disable it, but no one seemed to experience the same issue as I do. Every few minutes, this app creates a ~34MB log file in the C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\VsHub folder. Due to thousands of these files being created, the system partition has quickly filled up. I've disabled the vshub process and moved those logs to another partition, hovewer I still don't know the root of the problem.

What exactly is the vshub.exe responsibe for, do I need it, and why is it constantly logging?

I'm leaving an example log file below.
[HubController-eiott03m.0rz.log](http://www.filedropper.com/hubcontroller-eiott03m0rzlog)

Comment: We're running into the same thing, and in our case the HubController files only have exceptions. (`StartHttpService : Error : Failed to bind to port 49171.` Cause: a `System.Net.HttpListenerException` with message `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process` thrown in `System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()`.)  Your example logfile is not available anymore.  Could you update your question and put in a single occurrence of whatever is being repeatedly logged there?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The goal/responsibility of VsHub.exe is explained by someone from Microsoft here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33153720/223837.

> [...] the VS Hub is an out-of-proc services host that Visual Studio
>   (and other VS shell-based products such as Blend) use in order to
>   support multi-tool communication, better responsiveness within devenv
>   (VS), and enable certain services to extend past the lifetime of the
>   spawning process.

My guess is that, at least on a system where you only have SQL Server Management Studio, you cannot uninstall it.  (Although you might be able to disable it using the many links you already found, since you wrote "I've seen people asking how to disable it".)

I don't know what is in *your* log file, since the file you uploaded to filedropper.com has since expired.  But we are seeing VsHub\HubController temp files as well, and in our case it is continuously logging exceptions saying that `StartHttpService : Error : Failed to bind to port 49171.` (For different port numbers.)  And I see the same in a Windows 10 forum thread "Windows 10 loses some internet and browser connectivity about 24 hours after reboot" (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/windows-10-loses-some-internet-and-browser/6b3a55c9-d180-4d8e-9003-770522db719d?auth=1).  So the cause seems to be that TCP ports are exhausted.

Finally, about a potential fix: that same thread, in the October 17, 2017 response by user pasllc, points to a BizTalk-related article entitled "Avoiding TCP/IP Port Exhaustion" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610).  That article talks about setting 2 registry keys (TcpTimedWaitDelay and MaxUserPort), and the thread response talks also about setting a third (TcpMaxDataRetransmissions).

Comment: At the time of writing, my colleagues have not tried out the registry keys change. We'll do our best to report back if/when they do.